# How to get exactly one kafka config value?

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to get `replication-factor` or some other config like `compression.type` for a given topic.

Im aware that `kafka-topics --describe` will return me all the settings, but how to get exactly one config value?

like this:

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper zk:2181 --describe --topic testtopic1 --getReplicationFactor
```

The use case would be to check from a script whether a setting has a given value.

Is there any built in solution for this or should I manually parse to describe's output?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will need to parse it.
I suggest you to use the `./kafka-configs.sh` tool instead of `./kafka-topics` one.

In order to check config overrides on a given topic you can run:

```
./kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper <zk_host>:2181 --entity-type topics --entity-name <topic_name> --describe
```

And parse it.

Pay attention that it might be tricky because your topic can have server default configuration (which you can find in your config file -  `server.properties`) and even [Kafka defaults configs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs) that you won't see using those tools.

Another way to do so, that might be easier - depends on your use case, is to use the `KafkaAdminClient` from one of the available clients.
Here's an [example](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/tests/test_Admin.py#L217) using [Python](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaAdminClient.html#kafka.KafkaAdminClient.describe_configs).